# Find a space with regex under specific conditions

Tags: regex

```
ERY Som
```

I wanna find the space between those words:

I can find the text like this:

```
([A-Z]{3}\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})
```

But how can i select the space so i replace it with a \n?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't select the part you want to replace, you select the parts you want to keep. Then copy them to the result, with the replacement for space put in its place.

```
Match: ([A-Z]{3})\s([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})
Replace: $1\n$2
```